# Distributivity and Associativity for 32/64bit signed integers

Tags: numbers

I'm looking into 32/64bit signed integers and their algebraic properties. I am quite sure that the the three operators +, - and * fulfill the distributive and associative property (integer division does not because of the information loss) even though we have some kind of information loss due to wrapping of positive <-> negative numbers.

What I'm looking for is some kind of academic publication (if it is not too trivial) that addresses this issue and provides some proof or counterexample.

Comment: off-site resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]. See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: @gnat So it would be ok, to rephrase my question and not ask for offsite-links?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the mathematical properties of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*Integers modulo n* (ℤ/nℤ)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n) with addition and multiplication form a [*Commutative Ring*](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_ring), where multiplication distributes over addition. If n is prime, they even form a finite field.

I don't see why subtracting n/2 from every number (to make it signed) would necessarily change that.

For a definitive answer, [Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) is probably the better audience.

Comment: Thanks. This supports my assumption. I'll have a look at math.SX.